# Difference between index catalog_category_product and catalog_product_category

Tags: magento2, index

Could someone explain me what is the difference between the indexes **catalog_category_product** and **catalog_product_category**?

From db i see that **catalog_category_product** is related to table `catalog_category_product_index`, but i don't find to which table is related **catalog_product_category** index.

Comment: There is no `catalog_product_category` table in Magento 2.1.5 CE & `catalog_category_product` stores Category wise Product Info

Comment: Yes i see that, so what is the role of catalog_product_category index?

Comment: There is no `catalog_product_category` Index table as well

Comment: @AnkitShah I think my question is clear and you continue to give useless reply. What is the role of catalog_product_category index if it isn't related to any table? What does this index when run?

Comment: @AnkitShah Do you give vote down? Are you serious?

Comment: Nope I didn't given @Luca

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55883/discussion-between-luca-s-and-ankit-shah).

Comment: Why continue in chat? Now I have no idea what the outcome was. Please post any useful answers here.

Comment: That message was few month ago, i continued discussion in chat but without any usefull hints.

Comment: @all closed question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The real difference is in the partial reindexing features:

- the **catalog_category_product** index reindexes partially by Category ID (accepts list of category IDs to reindex);
- the **catalog_product_category** index reindexes partially by Product ID (accepts list of product IDs to reindex);

Both act on the same database tables, it's just the input that differs.

Comment: thank you Dmitri

Comment: @LucScu - my pleasure

Answer (score 1):

Looking deep in magento core files, you notice that **catalog_product_category** index model is `Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Category` that extends `Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product` that is the model of **catalog_category_product** index.

Both of them `$fullActionFactory` and `$rowsActionFactory` entities extends from `Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\AbstractAction` that has

```
const MAIN_INDEX_TABLE = 'catalog_category_product_index';
```

So we can say that both indexer works and save data on the same table `catalog_category_product_index`.

Answer (score 1):

`catalog_product_category` : the "true" data saved by product. Those are the categories checked in the back-office when you edit the product.

`catalog_product_category_index` : where the product are "really". Meaning, if the parent category  has "is_anchor" at yes, it means it has also the children category in it. So, it's "normal" to have both of those table.

Comment: My answer was about the difference between the two index catalog_product_category and catalog_category_product, nothing about db tables.